# List.files based on numbers

Tags: r, list

I am trying to create a list of files on which I want to run a function. I created a pattern which matches 35 files which I want to use.

```
mypattern <- paste0("NBS_NLoans_since2009_", seq(1, 35),".xls")

[1] "NBS_NLoans_since2009_1.xls"  "NBS_NLoans_since2009_2.xls"  "NBS_NLoans_since2009_3.xls"  "NBS_NLoans_since2009_4.xls" 
 [5] "NBS_NLoans_since2009_5.xls"  "NBS_NLoans_since2009_6.xls"  "NBS_NLoans_since2009_7.xls"  "NBS_NLoans_since2009_8.xls" 
 [9] "NBS_NLoans_since2009_9.xls"  "NBS_NLoans_since2009_10.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_11.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_12.xls"
[13] "NBS_NLoans_since2009_13.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_14.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_15.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_16.xls"
[17] "NBS_NLoans_since2009_17.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_18.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_19.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_20.xls"
[21] "NBS_NLoans_since2009_21.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_22.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_23.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_24.xls"
[25] "NBS_NLoans_since2009_25.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_26.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_27.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_28.xls"
[29] "NBS_NLoans_since2009_29.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_30.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_31.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_32.xls"
[33] "NBS_NLoans_since2009_33.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_34.xls" "NBS_NLoans_since2009_35.xls"
```

Then I used the pattern to get those files from my directory. I got only one file. I have tried different patterns but either I got one file or more than 35 files. Thanks for any suggestion.

```
list.files(pattern = mypattern)

[1] "NBS_NLoans_since2009_1.xls"
```

Comment: `lapply(mypattern,list.files)`

Comment: Thank you but I when I run it I get "character(0)"

Comment: I thought that pattern was the first argument, use instead `lapply(mypattern,function(x){list.files(pattern=x)})`.

Comment: Looks like the patterns are exactly the file names, so why do you use **list.files** ?